# output of top gets truncated to 80 columns when run by cron

Tags: cron, top

I have got the following logging script:

```
#!/bin/bash
top -b -c -n 1 >> /var/log/toplog/top.log
```

And the following record in my crontab:

```
*/1 * * * *     /home/clime/scripts/toplog.sh
```

The problem is that lines in top.log are being cut to 80 chars, e.g.:

```
 1512 root      20   0 80756 1436  572 S  0.0  0.1   0:05.92 /usr/libexec/postfi
```

This does not happen if I run the command directly from console.

I have tried to use COLUMNS variable:

```
*/1 * * * *     COLUMNS=999 /home/clime/scripts/toplog.sh
```

But that leads to every line being long exactly 999 characters - unused space is padded with spaces, which is not what I want.

How to fix this strange issue? My system is centos 6.3.

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant but what's the point of `/1`? Does it work if you simply use `* * * * *`? `*/1` and `*` both mean run every minute.

Comment: Ye, `/1` does not need to be there. I have changed it. The problem persists though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`top` always displays spaces until the last screen column. You just don't realize it when it's printing to the terminal because you can't visually distinguish a line with trailing spaces from a line without trailing space. You'll notice the spaces if you copy-paste with the mouse or in `screen`.

If you want to get rid of the spaces, just filter them away.

```
COLUMNS=9999 top -b -c -n 1 | sed 's/  *$//' >>/var/log/toplog/top.log
```

Whatever you're running `top` for, there are probably far better [monitoring](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitoring) tools available.

Comment: I use this to keep information about processes that were running at any time during last five days. These are 1-min snapshots so something might get lost but I think it is good enough for me. I want to have some data available when I  discover there was a peak in resource usage (I use munin for that). I haven't found a better way to keep track of past processes (tried psacct).

Comment: Just saw this when running a check script via nrpe. The output of `ps` was truncated to 80 chars and a grep for the process name was failing. Setting COLUMNS resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue. Bash script worked fine from the command line but the 'top' output was chopped to 80 chars when run from cron.

I first tried the accepted solution here, by setting the COLUMNS environment variable.  I could not get this to work (SLES 12.1).  I even tried to write to a file, export, source custom profile.

What did work was using top's -w option.
Here is the guts of my script, minus the notification and killing safety stuff.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/sh

PROC_FOUND=""
MAX_CPU=0

RETVAL="$(top -bc -n 1 -w 512 | tail -n+8 | awk -v cpulimit=$MAX_CPU '{if ($9>=cpulimit) print $1 " " $9 " " $12; }')"

IFS='
'
set -f
for line in ${RETVAL}; do
{
        echo "found [$line]" > /dev/tty

        IFS=', '
        read -r -a array <<< "$line"
        #echo "array is ... ${array[*]}"
        PID_VAL=${array[0]}
        CPU_VAL=${array[1]}
        PROC_FOUND=${array[2]}

        echo "Monitored a High CPU for process [${PROC_FOUND} ${PID_VAL}] on "${HOSTNAME}" where ${CPU_VAL}% >= ${MAX_CPU}%."
}
done
set +f
unset IFS
exit
```